# Is a clause "A" a tautology if and just if it contains both the atoms p and ¬p at the same time?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm just starting boolean algebra, and I'm kind of stuck here.

I know $A=(p \text{ or } ¬p)$ is a tautology, and what I've tried to do is to find an example of a tautological clause that does not include $p$ or $¬p$ at the same time, without success.

Any help?

Comment: Every tautology is reducible to this form, where in general $p$ may be a non-atomic formula.

Comment: What is your opinion of the form $p\to (q\to p) $?

Comment: $p\wedge\neg p$ contains the two things you say and it is not a tautulogy.

Comment: Perhaps you need to define "clause", so people won't attempt answers with formulas other than clauses.